# Is the relative discriminant a principal ideal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field, $E$ a quadratic extension of $F$. we know $\mathfrak d_{E/F}$ is a integral ideal in $\mathfrak o_F$. Is it a principal ideal? How to prove it ?

Thanks?

Comment: No. Take a quadratic field with class number $3$, let ${\mathfrak p}$ be a nonprincipal  ideal, and look for an ideal ${\mathfrak a}$ such that ${\mathfrak p} {\mathfrak a}^2  = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Then adjoin $\sqrt{\alpha}$.

Comment: In the other direction, the relative discriminant is always a square in the class group, so one is in good shape if $2$ annihilates the class group of $F$.

Comment: You're right. of course -(

Comment: As are you, dear @franzlemmermeyer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction given in the comments works in principle, but not with fields with odd class number, as The Potter's Vessel pointed out.

Let $K$ be a quadratic field with cyclic class group of order $4$ and 
${\mathfrak p}$ a prime ideal of odd norm $p$ in the class with order $2$. 
Find an element $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ whose norm has the form $pa^2$; then the quadratic extension $K(\sqrt{\alpha}\,)$ will ramify exactly at 
${\mathfrak p}$. Thus ${\mathfrak p}$ will be the relative discriminant, and it will not be principal.

As an example, take the prime $p = 89$ in $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-17})$. Since
$2p = N(5+3\sqrt{-17})$, genus theory tells us that the ideal class of the prime above $p$ is a square but not trivial. Now consider the element 
$\alpha = -23 + 4\sqrt{-17} \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Its square root generates the extension $L/K$ defined by a root of $f(x) = x^4 + 46x^2 + 801$. The field discriminant is $\Delta = (4 \cdot 17)^2 \cdot 89$, hence exactly $89$ is ramified in the quadratic extension $L$, and thus the prime ideal above $89$ is the relatice discriminant.

Comment: Dear Franz, this example is correct, but so was your example in the comments. My comment was only to remark that if the class group is $(\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^m$ for some $m$ then the relative discriminant will always be principal. This doesn't rule out odd class numbers (besides $1$) at all! (Every element in a group of odd order is a square, so the extra restriction is vacuous.)